# Why does input[type="text"] change size on focus?

Tags: html, css, input

Say I have an input.

html

```
<input type="text">
```

css:

```
input, input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: solid 1px grey;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

When clicked, the input changes size. How do I stop this?

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/QwVvZK

Comment: No, it doesn't. [Firefox 36]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking in Chrome, it's because of the following default user-agent styling:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus,
keygen:focus, select:focus {
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Therefore you need to set the [`outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset) to `0` when focusing on the element:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raZmQp)

```
input:focus {
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! you've saved me a lot of nerves. It had almost blown my mind. Thank you a whole lot!

Comment: Note: A similar effect can also happen on mobile if you set the height of your input in vh unit because of the keyboard that shows up on viewport